# Stopping background Music after Activity Destroy Android

Tags: android

I was able to successfully play the background music on launch of my application, its only 1 activity (one page).
However the problem is when i click back button to exit the application... It closes and the music closes but it gives me stopped unexpectedly error, then after few seconds the music just start playing without any way to stop it.

here is my activity code calling the stop function

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{ 
        mServ.onDestroy();
}
```

and this is the MusicService part code:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy()

{
     mPlayer.stop();
     mPlayer.release();

}
```

Please help me resolve this issue as I'm out of ideas!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Adding Background Music](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App) .... Try to implement the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but that is exactly what i did and it didn't help, that's why i implemented some changes and its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you still having problem try the code below on the activity where you want to stop the music /sounds it work for me also i use from here https://github.com/alexsilva/MusicService/blob/master/src/com/example/mediaservice/MainActivity.java

if you create your code according to this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App (which not work for me at least).

use mServ.stopMusic(); to stop music/sounds ,

```
public void onRestart(){
  super.onRestart();
       mServ.stop();
   }
```

also don't call onDestroy() on your activities to stop service  it will Destory every thing actually :D

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, in your activity, after stopping the music, enter `stopService(music);` where music is the name of your Intent.